# x32 ASM Compiled (With NASM) for x64 Syscalls not working

Tags: linux, assembly, nasm, system-calls

The System calls like:

1 - exit
3 - read
4 - write

They work fine. However, calls like:

11 - execve
29 - pause

They do NOT work. I've tried using both hex and decimal (simply to make sure I wasn't messing up on that end). Please help!

Something simple:

```
SECTION .text
    global _start
_start:
    xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    mov al, 29
    int 80h
```

Here's how I'm compiling. I'm running x64 bit Arh Linux and compiling with NASM to emulate i386:

```
nasm -f elf32 -o temp.o file.asm
ld -s -m elf_i386 -o exec temp.o
rm temp.o
./exec
```

Rather than pausing or anything, I get nothing. It just stops (no, it's not pausing). I can type, I can hit enter, I can do whatever I want. Once I `ctrl+c`, it closes. But it's not a pause.

Answer (score 1):

This appears to work for me on x86_64 Archlinux. How are you certain it's not pause()ing?

strace'ing for me indicates that pause() does get called and produces the same characteristics you described above. Sending a SIGHUP to that process from another terminal also resumes execution for me.

Please provide strace output.